# Rendering in javaFX when resizing is very very slow / laggy. Why?

Tags: java, javafx

My Program is drawing a lot of `GridTile10`s like this:

Main Program:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    private static final int gridSize = 40;
    private static double zoomFactor = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400, true);
        scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
        stage.setFullScreenExitHint("");

        scene.setOnScroll((ScrollEvent event) -> {
            double deltaY = event.getDeltaY();

            if (deltaY > 0) {
                zoomFactor += 0.01;
            } else {
                zoomFactor -= 0.01;
                if (zoomFactor <= 0) {
                    zoomFactor = 0.01;
                }
            }
            updateTransforms(root);
        });

        scene.widthProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            resetSize(scene, root);
        });
       
        scene.heightProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            resetSize(scene, root);
        });

        stage.setTitle("Visualisation");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        File file = new File(INPUT);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        ArrayList<String> pipes = new ArrayList<>();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            pipes.add(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        scanner.close();
        GridTile10[][] pipeTiles = new GridTile10[pipes.size()][pipes.get(0).length()];
        GridTile10 startTile = makeGrid(root, gridSize, pipes, pipeTiles, scene);

        resetSize(scene, root);
    }

    private static GridTile10 makeGrid(Group root, int gridSize, ArrayList<String> grid, GridTile10[][] gridTiles, Scene scene) {
        GridTile10 startTile = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid.get(i).length(); j++) {
                GridTile10 newGridTile = new GridTile10(i * gridSize, j * gridSize, gridSize, grid.get(i).charAt(j));
                root.getChildren().add(newGridTile);
                gridTiles[i][j] = newGridTile;
                if (gridTiles[i][j].getChar() == 'S') {
                    startTile = gridTiles[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return startTile;
    }

    private static void resetSize(Scene scene, Group root) {
        root.setLayoutX((scene.getWidth() - root.prefWidth(-1)) / 2);
        root.setLayoutY((scene.getHeight() - root.prefHeight(-1)) / 2);

        double scaleX = scene.getWidth() / root.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
        double scaleY = scene.getHeight() / root.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();
        zoomFactor = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY) - 0.01;
        updateTransforms(root);
    }

    private static void updateTransforms(Group root) {
        root.setScaleX(zoomFactor);
        root.setScaleY(zoomFactor);
    }
}
```

`GridTile` class:

```
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class GridTile extends Group {

    protected int x;
    protected int y;
    protected int size;
    protected Rectangle rectangle;

    public GridTile(int x, int y, int size) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.size = size;
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, size, size);
        rectangle.setFill(null);
        rectangle.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
        this.getChildren().add(rectangle);
        this.rectangle = rectangle;
    }

    public void resetColor() {
        this.rectangle.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return y/size;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return x/size;
    }
}
```

`GridTile10` class:

```
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;

public class GridTile10 extends GridTile {
    
    private char c;
    private Shape shape;

    public GridTile10(int y, int x, int size, char c) {
        super(x, y, size);
        this.setChar(c);
    }

    public Paint checkColor() {
        return this.rectangle.getFill();
    }

    public char getChar() {
        return this.c;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.rectangle.setFill(color);
    }

    public void setChar(char c) {
        this.c = c;
        if (shape != null) {
            this.getChildren().remove(this.shape);
        }
        if (c != '.' && c != 'S') {
            switch (c) {
                case '-':
                    shape = new Line(x, y + size / 2, x + size, y + size / 2);
                    break;
                case '|':
                    shape = new Line(x + size / 2, y, x + size / 2, y + size);
                    break;
                case 'F':
                    shape = new Arc(x + size, y + size, size / 2, size / 2, 90, 90);
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    shape = new Arc(x + size, y, size / 2, size / 2, 180, 90);
                    break;
                case '7':
                    shape = new Arc(x, y + size, size / 2, size / 2, 0, 90);
                    break;
                case 'J':
                    shape = new Arc(x, y, size / 2, size / 2, 270, 90);
                    break;
            }
            this.shape.setTranslateZ(-1);
            this.shape.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            this.shape.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
            this.shape.setStrokeWidth(5);
            this.getChildren().add(shape);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem arises when the grid is too big, in this case the test `input.txt` is not the problem because it is only 10x20. But when the input is 140x140 meaning about 20000 `GridTile10`s are drawn, the lag when resizing a window becomes the problem for my computer. It may take from 1-5 seconds with my computer to update as it should.
`test.txt`:

```
FF7FSF7F7F7F7F7F---7
L|LJ||||||||||||F--J
FL-7LJLJ||||||LJL-77
F--JF--7||LJLJ7F7FJ-
L---JF-JLJ.||-FJLJJ7
|F|F-JF---7F7-L7L|7|
|FFJF7L7F-JF7|JL---7
7-L-JL7||F7|L7F-7F7|
L.L7LFJ|||||FJL7||LJ
L7JLJL-JLJLJL--JLJ.L
```

`input.txt`

```
F-|F|7LJ7F7.L-J7L-L-7L-J7.FF.F|--J.L-7--7.L-7FFFF7-F|---F--L-FF-FF|.L.F|77|--7-.FF7-7--L7.-7F-7FL-7FFF-777FF-L-L.L-F.|--7.77-LF7-|F--|---777
|-7FF|||F7J.FJL|.L7LL7F|J7.J.|.|JF-7LLJJL-JJLFJLL7F||.FFJ||.LFJF7.LJ.F7|L-J7J|.L-JF7|F77F7J|7.LJ|LFJLLLLJ7F|.L-.-F-J7LJ-7FJL7FLL7L7JJ..JL-7|
F7|-LJF-F--LJ-FF7L|7FJJLF7FF-J-|-F.L.L7LLL7|F7JLF---.F-LJ|F-JL7L7-7.FLLJFF-|L-L7JJJ.--LJ-JJL--7L||F7.|-J.FFFJ.|.LL7L-.FFLJJ-JL-FJJL-77-|JLLJ
-J|.|F7LJ..|LFJ-J7|J|J-||JF|7||..|-7F7L-7.|-LF7.F7|7.-J|LF|---J7|||F7|L|-|.|F.LL-7-|||JLFLF7JLL-L-LJFF7-7-LJFFL..FJ.|.FFJLJ|JJ7|7L7J7--J.|F|
FFFJ||J.LFJJLJ7.J7|-77-L|-FL-L-F.LL|LJ|FJ-FJF||-F7F7-|FF7FF7J7|--J.-.J-L-FFLJ.FL7L|.|L|FJ.L|.7J|LJ|.||L7L7J.-J||F77F77L|J7LLJ.FL7J|LL7FLJFJ7
J7.|-L-|-LJ|7.|-L-J7L7-|F-7.7|F|.|JF7.LJL|L7F||FJLJL-7-FF7||-7LJFJJ.FJ7J.LJ7.7JLLF7L|7L|LF-LFF7-.|F-LJJF7LJ-|.7J77||F7J.|J-F---J|-|7||F|-7-J
|L77J-7J77|-|--..|L7FJ||L7LJLJ||.FFJF-L7FF-F-J||F----J-FJLJ|F77L7|.7LLL.-J7L-J-F-JL--7FL.|-7||||.77JFJ-F|L7.-LJL|7LF|J|FJ7-LJ..FL--.F7.7-LF7
||.---FJF-|.7J.L-77.F.FL7.-J77L|7L|FL|J|-J.L-7LJ|F77|7.L--7LJL-7JF-F7JF7J.777L77JFF--FF7-LJFF7F--7..||LLL7L7J-7JJ|7|L|-7F7.|FFJ||-J-7JFF.FL7
LF-L-F|7|.7.F-FJ-|---7||.FL--JJJL-77FF7|FJ7..L-7||L7JF----JF---JFF7||JF-7-L77-J--|LJF-7777FFJ||F-J--LJ.L-L7JJF-77LFL-7-|-J|-F7JF.F|-J|7L-7-|
-|7.-LJJ-LL.F7|.|..|-LJF-7|7.F|.L-LLFF-7JFFF--7|||FJLL----7L7F7|FJLJL77.|J-F77J|-7JL|FJF7F7L7||L-77.|J7..|F7-F7||-F-FJ|J|FJF-J7|7JLJJL|LL-7|
|L-7L|FL-||7|L|J7F|77..LFJF---L-|JF7FL7L7F7L-7LJLJL7F7-F--JFJ||FJF---J.F|FF||J.F--7FJ|F||||FJ||F-JF7F--7F-J|F77---JJF-F-F|J|.LFJJF.|LJ.L7L-J
77JFF|-|--7--J.|.FJ.F7-FJ.J7|.|L7-|FF7L7|||F7L7F7F7||L7L--7L7||L7|F----7FF7||-FJF-JL7|FJLJ|L7||L-7||L-7|L-7LJ||F|77.|J|LF|F-7JL-7J-L7F|.L7FL
L|.FF-7JJLLJF|-7FJJ7L7F-77F-7FL-F-F7||FJ|||||FJ|LJ|||FJF7FJFJ|L7|LJF---JF|LJL7L7L7F7||L-7FJJ|LJF7LJ|F-JL-7|F-JF-7-|-|-J7LL|FJ...77LFL|J7LFJ.
7.|L77L77.F7-J--|J.|FFL7L-J-JFFJ|.|LJLJFJ||||L-JF7|LJL7||L7L7L7||F-JF7F-7|F-7L-JFJ|||L7F||F7L7FJ|F-JL-7F-J|||FJFJ-7J|77|-L|L7F7F7----LL--|.F
--7-|JL7-.F7JF-7LL-.L|L--77|.|-F-7L---7L7|||L7F7||L-7FJ||L|FJFJ||||FJLJFJ||L|F--JFJLJFJFJ|||FJL7LJF7F7|L7FJL7L7L-7|-|-||F7|FJ|LJ|||.L|.L-J-L
J7FFJJ-LJ7||FJ.F7||.FJJ7F|--7JLL7L7F-7L7|||L7LJLJL7||L7||FJL7L7LJL7|F--J-LJFJL7F7L--7L-JFJ||L-7L7FJLJ||FJL7FJFJF-J7F7-F7|LJ|FJF-J77L-|---|.J
FF7L7|-J.F--FJ7LJFF-J7LJ-JFL|7J|L7||FJ|||||LL7F--7L7|FJ||L-7|-|F--J||F77F7FJF7LJL7F7|F-7L-JL7FJFJL--7||L7FJL7L7|F77||FJLJF7||FJF--7J.--F-F7.
7.J.L--L--JFJLJJ7L|JF7.|.|J-|J|F-JLJL7FJ||L7FJ|F-JFJ||FJ|F-JL-JL7F7|LJL7||L-J|F-7|||LJ|L7F--JL7|LF7FJ||FJL-7L7|||L7|FL--7||LJL-JF-JFJJ||F7--
--L--JF|7||L-F.L77..||FJ-LJ.77-L----7|L7|L7LJFJL-7|||LJFJ|F7F-7FJ||L--7|||F7-|L7LJ||F7F7|L7F7FJL-J|L7|||F7FJFJ|||FJ-F-F7LJL-7F--JFJ7-F--||L|
|-L7F|-L-7|L-JF7-F7-J77FJFJ.F7-|F-77||FJL7L--JF-7|L7|F7L7LJLJFJL-JL7LFJLJLJ|FJFJF-J||||LJFJ|LJF---JFJ|||||L7|L|LJL7JFJ||F-7J||7LJF||-LL-FJ-|
77-F.JL|L-|FLF|L|.F-|.FL7|JFJL-7|FJFJ||F-JF7F7L7|L7|||L-JF-77L--7F-JFJF7F--JL7|J|F-J||L-7L7L-7|F--7L7||LJL7|L7L--7||F7||L7|FJL7L7LF77LL-FJF7
.|7LJ7FF7|LL-7J7L-7FL-J.|JFL--7||L7L7LJL77||||FJ|FJLJL7F7L7|F---JL7FJFJ|L77F7|L7|L7FJ|F7L7L--J||F-JFJ||F--J|FJFF7||FJ|||FJ|L7FJ.LFJ|7JFL.L7J
F|L7|-F|-77LFL-F77|-J7|-|.FF--J||FJ-L-7FJFJ|||L7|L-7F-J||FJ|L--7F7||FJ-L7|FJLJFJ|FJL7LJL7L-7F-J|L7FJFJ||F7FJ|JFJ|||L7|||L7|FJL-77L7L-77L-7JJ
L|JLJ--F-L-JL7JL-J.LFFFF7F7L--7LJL-7|FJL7L7LJ|7||F7||F7|||FJLF7LJ|LJL7F7LJL7F7L7|L--JF--JF-JL-7L7|L7|-||||L7L7|FJ||FJLJ|FJ|L7F-JF7|F-J77.|F7
FJL7JJ.J-J.-J|7.|-|F-F-JLJ|7-LL--7FJFJF-JFL7FJFJLJLJLJLJ||L-7||F-JF-7LJL--7||L7|L7F-7L7F7L-7F-JFJ|FJ|FJLJ|FJFJ||FJ|L--7|L7|FJL--JLJL--7-7-|J
FLJ.7F7.|.FJ|-|7F.F7LL--7FJF7F7F7|L7|FJF7F7|L7|F7F----7FJ|F-J||L-7L7L-----JLJ||||LJFJFJ||.FJL7FJFJL7LJF--J|FJFJ||FJF7FJ|FJ||F---7F-7F-JJ7.L7
F7F|LF7-JF7.7JL-JL||F7J|||FJ||LJ|L7||L7||||L7|||||F--7||F|L-7||F7|FJF--7F--7F-JL7JFJFJFJL7|F7|L7|F-JF7L7JFJL7|FJ|L7|||FJL7LJ|.F7LJFLJ||L7-L|
J7J|FLL7.LL7J.LJ7||LJ|F7||L7|L-7|F|LJFJ|LJ|FJ|||LJL-7||L7|F-J|LJ||L7|F-JL-7|L--7|FJFJFJF-JLJ||FJ|L7FJL-JFJF7LJL7|FJ||||7-|F-JFJL7F7F777LF7.7
|JF-JLFJ.LJ|.F77FL|F7LJLJ|FJ|F7|L-JF7L-JF-JL7|LJF7F-JLJFJ|L77L-7|L7||L--7FJL---JLJFJ7L7|.F7-||L7|FJL7F7|L-JL7F-J|L-JLJL7FJL--JF7||LJL-7-||.L
|J-LJ7LJF-77-LF-F|LJL---7|L7|||L---J|F-7L7F-J|F-J|L---7|FJFJF7FJ|FJLJF--JL7F-----7L-7FJL7|L7||-||L-7LJL7F7F7||F-JF-----J|F-7F7|LJ|F7F-JF-J77
|.L|L|LF--J|L|J---F-7F7|||F||||-F7F-J|F|FJL-7|L7FJF---J|L7|||||FJL--7L7JF7LJF7F-7|F7||F7||FJ|L7||F7L7F-J|||||LJF7|F-----JL7|||L--J||L777JJFJ
L..F7L-..|-|F||.|7L7LJ|FJ|FJLJL7|||F7L7LJF7FJL7|L7L---7L7||FJ|||F7F7L7L7|L7FJ|L7LJ|LJ||LJ||JL7LJ||L7|L--J||||F-JLJL----7F-JLJL-7F7|L7L7||FL.
L---|-LJFL-FLF--7F||F7|L7LJF--7|||LJL7|F7||L-7||FJF7F7L7|||L7|||||||7L7||FJL7|FL7FJF7||F7||F7L7FJL7||F---J|||L7F7F7.F--JL---7F7LJLJ-L7|-7F-7
LJ-LJ-|FJ--.L|F-JF7LJ|L7L--JF7|||L7F7||||||F-J||L7|LJL7||||FJ||||LJL7FJ||L7FJ|F7|L7|||||LJ|||FJ|F7|||L7F7FJLJFJ|LJL7L-7F----J|L7F77-L||F-7-J
|..L..-|L77F-JL-7||F7L7L----JLJLJFJ||||||||L7FJ|FJL-7FJ||||L7||||F--JL7||FJ|FJ|||FJ||||L7FJ|||FJ|||||FJ|||F--JFJF--J.FJL----7|FJ||77|LJ7LJ||
F|7-JJ--7F-JF7F7LJLJ|LL---------7|FJ|||||||FJ|FJ|F7FJ|FJ||L7|||||L7F7FJ||L7||FJ||L7|||L7|L7||||FJ||LJL7|LJL--7L7|FF7FJF--7F-J|L-JL7F7.|JJFL7
||F7|JF7FL7FJ|||F--7L-7F7F----7J||L7||||||LJFJ|-LJ|L7|L7||FJ||||L7||||J||FJ|||FJ|FJ||L7LJLLJ|||L7LJF--J|F----JFJL-J|L7|F7LJ|FJF-7FJ|L7|F-7J|
-LLJL-|F-LLJ|LJLJF-JF7LJ|L---7L-JL-JLJ|||L-7L7L7F-JFJL7||||FJ|||FJ||LJFJ|L7|LJL7||FJL7L-7.F-J|L7L-7L7F-JL----7L7F--JFJLJL---JFJFJL-JFJ-|JF-7
FJF|-LL--|F---7F7L7FJL7FJF7F7L-------7||L7FJFJFJL7FJ.FJ||||L7LJ||7LJF7|FJFJ|F--J|||F7L-7L7L-7|FJF-JF||F7F----JFJL---JF--7F---JLL-7F-JF7J.|FJ
L|-JF|J---L--7LJL7LJ|FJ|FJ||||F7-F---JLJFJL7L7|F-JL7FJFJ|||FJF-JL-7L||||-L7||F--J|LJL-7|FJF-J|L7L7F7LJ||L-----JF-7F7FJF7|L--7F7F7LJF-J|FFJL7
LLLJFJF7JJJ7FJF-7L7F7L7|L7LJL-JL7L----7JL-7L7|||F-7|L7|FJ|LJFL-7F7L-J|||F-J|||F--JF-7FJLJFJF7L7|FJ|L--JL7F7F---JFJ||L-J|L--7||LJ|F7|F-JFJF-J
LFF7L7L|7JFFL7L7L7LJ|FJL7L-----7L-----JF7J|FJ||LJFJL7||L7L--7F-J|L7F7|LJL-7|LJL7F7|FJL-77L-JL7|LJFJF7F-7|||L-7F7L-JL7F7L-7FJLJF-J||||F-JFJJJ
.-|JJFLF777F-L-J7L-7|L-7|F7F---JF------JL7|L7|L7FL-7|||7|F-7|L-7L7LJ|L7F--JL7F-J|||L7F7L--7F7LJ7FJFJ||FJLJL-7LJL---7||L7FJL---JF7|||LJF-J|FJ
.F|JLF7|L7-|.F7-F7FJL--J|||L----JF-----7FJL-JL7L--7LJ|L7|L7||JFJFJ-FJFJL----JL7FJ|L7|||F-7||L---JFJFLJL7F7F7L------J|L7|L7F----JLJLJF7L-7JF|
-FJJJ|||FJFF7||FJLJF7F-7|||F7F7F7L----7||F7F77L---JF-JFJ|FJ|L7L7L-7L-JF-7F7F--JL7L-J|||L7|||F7F-7L-7F-7LJLJL-------7|FJL7LJF-7F7F--7|L-7|FJ7
F7JF7|LJ|-FJ|||L---JLJFJLJ||LJ|||F----JLJ|LJL----7.L-7L7|L7|FJJ|F7L-77L7LJLJF-7FJF--J||FJLJLJLJFJF-JL7L-----7F-7F--JLJF7L-7L7LJ|L-7LJ.LLJFJ7
FLFJ|L-7L-JFJ|L------7L7F7|L-7|||L-------JF--7F--JF-7|FJL-J|L-7LJ|F-JF-JF--7|.LJ.L-7FJ|L7F-7|F7L7L7F-JF--7JFJL7|L-----JL-7L7L-7|F7|F7-F-77|.
-7L7|F7L--7L7L-7F7F-7L-J||L--JLJL-7F7F7F7FJFFJL-7JL7LJL--7FJF7|F-J|F7L-7|F-JL--7F--J|LL-JL7L-JL-JFJL7FJF7L7L7FJL---------J7L-7|LJ|LJ|FJFJ.F7
LLJ|LJL--7|FJFFJ|LJ-L---JL7F7F---7LJLJLJ||F7L7F-JF7L-7F7FJL7|||L-7LJ|-FJ|L7F7F-JL7F7L----7L7F-7F-JF7LJFJL-J|LJ-F7|F----7F--77LJF-JF7|L7|F7||
|LFL-7F-7LJL-7|FJF--7F--7FLJLJLF7L-----7|LJ|FJL--J||FJ||L-7||||F-JF7L7|FJFJ||L-7|LJL7F---JFJL7||F-J|F7L---7F--7||FJF7F-J|F7L--7L-7|LJFJLJLJ|
7|..FJ|FJF-7FJLJFL-7LJF7L------JL------JL7FJL7F--7|FJFJL7FJLJ||L7FJL7||L7L7||F7L-7F7|L--7FJF7|LJL-7|||F77FJ|F-J|LJFJLJF7||L---JF7|||FJF7F7FJ
|LF-L-JL7|FJL------JF7|L-7F-7F----------7|||FJL7FJ|L7L-7LJF7J||FJ|F-J||FJFJ|LJ|F7||LJF-7|L-JLJJF7FJLJLJL-JJ||FFJF7L---JLJL-7-F7||LJFJFJLJLJJ
JJLF--7FLJL-7F-7F7F7|LJF-J|7LJF-----7F--J|L7L--JL-JFJF7L--JL7||L7||F7|||FJFJF7||LJ|F7L7LJF7F-7FJLJF7F7F----JL-JFJL7F------7L-J|||F-JFJJ-LJ|.
|F|L-7L--7F-J|FJ|||LJ|FJF7|F--JF7F-7LJ-F7L-JF--7F7|L7||F7F7FJLJJ|||||||||FJFJLJL-7LJL7L-7||L7|L---JLJLJF----7F-J7FJL-7-F77L---J||L7FJJJJJJJ.
L7F|FL--7||F7|L-J||F--JFJLJL--7|LJFL---JL7F7|F-J|L-7||||||||F---J|||LJ||||FL-7F7FJF-7L7FJ|L-JL-7FF7F7F7L---7|L--7L--7L-JL7FF7JFJL-JL--7-|-77
L|J|FLF-JLJ||L--7LJL---JF-----J|-F---7F-7LJ|||JFJF7|||||LJ||L-7F-J|L-7||||F--J||L7L7L7||FJF7F-7L-JLJLJL-7F7|L-7FJF7-|F7F7L-JL-JF------JL7L|7
.|F-FFJF--7|L7F-JF---7F7L---7F-JFJF7-LJ||F7LJL-JFJLJLJLJF7LJF7||JLL7FJLJ|||F7FJL7L-JFJLJL-J|L7L7F7F7F7F7LJLJF7LJFJL7LJLJL7F7F-7L-7F7-F7||-J|
LJ7FLL-JF-JL7|L7FJF-7LJL----J|F7L-JL--7FJ||F--7FJJF--7F7|L7FJLJ|7-LLJ-LJLJ|||L7.L7F7L-7F---JFJ|LJLJLJLJL--7FJL7FJF-JF7F7|||||-|F7LJL-JL7|.F|
|L-F-LL-L7F7|L7|L-JL|F----7F-J|L----7FJL7|||F-JL--JF7LJLJFJL7F7|--|L7..|LFJ||FJF7||L--JL----JF--7F7F7FF---JL7FJL7L--JLJL7LJ||FJ||F-7F7FJ777J
J.|L-7|.|||||JLJF---J|F---J|F7L----7LJF7LJLJL-7F-7FJ|F7F7|7.LJLJ|F7LFF-LLL-JLJFJLJ|F-7F7F7F77|F7LJLJL-JF--7FJL--JF7F-7F7L-7|||FJ|L7||LJF7.|F
LLJ7LJ7-LLJLJFF-JF---JL7F--J|L----7L--JL7F7F7FJL7LJFLJ|||L7-LL|.7L|JLL7.|-|.LFJF-7|L7LJLJLJL7LJL--7F7F7|F-J|F----JLJJ||L--J||LJFJFJ|L--J|-|J
FJL7.L|L|.LF--JF7|7F77FLJF-7L----7L---7FJ|||||F7L-7F-7LJ|FJ7.LL-JFJJ7-LJ--LF-L7|FJL7|F7F-7F7L7JF7LLJLJLJL--JL-7F--7F7|L7FF7LJF7L7|FJF-7FJJ.L
LF.L77JF-.FL7F7|LJFJL7F-7L7L77F7.L---7LJFJLJ|LJL--J|FJLFJ|J7..FLLJ.F7.7JJ||J.LLJL--JLJ||FJ|L7L7||F7F7F----7F-7LJF7LJ|L-JFJL-7|L7|||FJ|LJJF-7
FF-7L|F-JF-LLJLJF7L-7|L7|F|FJFJL7F---JF7|F--JF-----J|F7L7|-L-F77|L.FJFJFF-|.F7LF7F-7F7LJL7|7L7LJLJ|||L---7|L7L--JL--JF7F|F--J|FJLJ|L7--LLJ-7
F--J--LJFJLF7F7FJ|F-JL7||FJL-JF7|L----J||L---JF7F7F-J|L7LJ7J..LL-JFF-FLLJJL7-|F||L7|||F--JL7-L---7||L----JL7L--------JL-JL-7L|L--7L-J|JLFJ||
|-|-7JFFJ7.|LJLJFJL7F7LJLJF7F-J|L------J|F----J||||F7|FJLF7|-7-|L|L7--J|LJ|L-LL|L-JLJLJF7F-JF----J||F7F---7|F-7F--7F---7F-7L-JF--JF7F7.|FF--
J7FF-7FJ||FJF--7L-7LJL---7|LJF-JF--7F---JL-7F7JLJLJ|LJL7FJ|F77.J--JLL|F7L-LJ..LL-7F7F7FJLJF7L-7F-7|LJLJF--JLJ-|L-7|L--7LJFJF-7|F7F||||.|JL|.
|LL-|-7F--L-JF-JF7L------JL7LL--JF-J|F--7F7LJL7F7F-JF-7LJFJ7LJ-J.|.F.J-J-J|F77F--J||||L-7FJL7FJ|FJL--7-L---7F7L--JL7F7L-7|FJ||LJ|7|||L-7-.|L
7.|.|JL|J7LF-JF7||F7F------JF-7F7L--JL-7||L---J|||F7|L|F7L7J777.7-L7.L-7|7J|LFL---J|||F-JL7FJL-J|F-7FJF----J||F7FF7|||F-J|L-7|F7L-JLJF7|LFFJ
|J-F7--J.L.L7FJLJLJLJF--77F7L7|||F--7F-JLJFF7F7|LJ||L7LJL-JJ.77JJ.F|.LF-FJ.F7.F----J|LJ|F-JL----J|FJL7L--7F-J||L-J||||L7FL--JLJL-7F7FJLJ7F-7
|F|.LJ||FJ.FJ|F-----7L-7L-JL-JLJ|L-7|L--7F7|LJ||F-JL-JF---7..7J.FJ-F7L-.|--L7-|F-7F7|F-7L------7FJ|F7L7F7||F-J|F--J||L7L-7F7F---7||LJ.|J7JL-
FL|-LJL7JJFL-JL--7F7L7FJF-7F7F-7L--JL7F-J|||F7LJL--7F7L7F-J77.F-L|.J|FJ.L7..F7LJ.LJ||L7|F7F7F--JL7||L7LJLJ|L7FJL--7|L7|F7||LJF7FJLJ7-||FL7.|
.LJ-J-LL77-|LF---J|L7LJFJ.|||L7L7F--7|L--JLJ||F7F-7LJL-JL-7-7F77-.|J7|FLLJ.FLJ7F-|LLJFJLJLJLJF-7FJ|L7L7F-7|FJ|F---JL-JLJLJ|F-JLJJFLL-L-FJ-J7
F|J..L||LJ7LFL-7F7|-L-7L7FJ|L-JFLJFFJL------JLJ|L7L7F--7F-J-L-J-JFJ--7F.|F7.L.|JL|-F-JF---7F7|FLJ7L-J.LJ.LJL-JL-7F7F7F7F7FJL-7F7-F7|.|.LFJLJ
7---7F-7JF||L|FLJLJF7FJFJL-J|F7F7F7L----------7L7L7||F7|L-7-FJFJ-JLFJ|J-F||7.LJ|LF7L-7|F--J||L7F--7F7F------7F7FJ|LJLJ|||L7F-J||7||F--77.F7|
LJ||L|.L.JLJ|.F7F-7||L-JF7-F-JLJLJL-7F--------JLL-JLJ||L--JF-777FLFF7.|7FJL7-.LF-JL-7LJL-7FJ|FJL-7|||L-7F--7LJLJJ|F---J|L-JL-7|L7|LJF7||LJ-7
-J-|J|..F|.LF-J|L7LJL---JL-JF7F7F7F7|L----7F---7F----J|F7J|||LF-7J.F7-7FJF7|.F|L---7|F7F7LJ-LJF--JLJL-7LJF-J-F7F7||F7-FJF7F7FJ|FJL7FJLJ-L|7F
|7LL-J.L--7F|F7L-JF---7F----JLJ||LJ||F----J|F--J|F7F7FJ|L--77LL7||F||FFJFJ||-FF7F--JLJLJL7F-7FJF7F---7L--JF--JLJLJLJL-JFJ|||L-JL--JL--7J7F--
|F.FL-L-F-FLLJ|F-7|F-7LJF7FF---J|F-JLJF7F7FJL---J|LJ|L-JF7FJ7FFJL7FJL-JFJ|||-||LJF7F7F7F7LJFJL-JLJF77L----JF-7F--7F7F--J-|||F7F-7F7F7FJ-L.FL
L--L.7J-J|.|L|LJLLJL7L--JL-JF-7FJL----JLJLJF7F7F7L-7|F--JLJ|.FL-7LJF--7L-7LJF7L--JLJLJLJL-7L7F-7JFJL7F7F7F-JFJL-7|||L---7LJ||||7LJ||LJJ|L-F7
FJJ.-.F.7LF|.F-----7L---7F-7|FJ|F----7F----JLJLJL--JLJ.F-77F77LLL--J.FJF7L-7||F7F--7F-----JFJL7|FJF7LJ||LJF7L---J||L-7F7L7LLJ|L-7FLJJLFFJ|L-
|J7LL-7F7.-J7L--7F7|F---JL7||L-JL---7|L----7F7F7.F7LF--JFJFJ|JLF-7F-7L7|L--J|LJLJF7|L-7F--7L--JLJFJ|F7LJF-JL----7|L-7LJL-JF-7L7FJF7|7F-|F|J|
|||-LLL|-LF-7JFFJ||LJF7F7FJ||F------JL----7LJLJL-JL-JF7FJJ|FJ7FL7LJFJFJL---7L---7|LJ.FJ|F-JF-7F-7L7LJL7FJF-----7|L7FJF-7F7|FJFJL-JL--7-.|J--
LJ--7JL|7||-77FL-JL-7|||||7LJL-----------7L7F-7F7F---JLJF-JL-7F7L-7L-JF----JF---J|F7FJFJ|F7|FLJLL7|F-7LJFJF--77LJ|LJ||FJ|||L7|F-7F7F7|JFFJ|L
LJ-FL.LL--JFJF7JFF--J|||LJF7-F---------7FJJ|L7LJLJ-F---7L--7FJ||F7L--7|F7.F7L---7|||L7|-LJ||F-7F7LJL7|F7L-JF7L7.F7JF-JL-JLJFJ||FJ|LJLJFFL-JJ
.|J|L-77.JFL-||7FJF-7|||F-JL7L--------7LJF7L-JF7.F7|F--JF7FJL7||||.F7|||L-JL-7.FJLJ|-LJF7FJ|L7LJ|.F-JLJL---JL7L-JL-JF7F7F-7L7LJL7L7J-L-.LL7.
LJ-F|JF|.F7J-|L-JFJ.LJLJL--7|F7F7F7F-7L--J|JF7||FJLJL7F7||L7FJ|||L7|LJ||F----JFJF-7|F--J|L-J7L7FJFJF---7F---7|F--7F-J||LJ7|FJJ-LL-JF7LL-7L77
|.|.|.-JFFLJFL-7FJF-7F7F--7|LJLJLJLJFL-7F7L-J||LJF7F7|||||FJ|FJ||FJL-7LJ|.F--7L-JFJ|L-7FJF7|F-JL7L-JF--J|F7FJLJF7|L-7LJF-7||JL77.|-7J.L|FJL7
.F7.-7FF777FLJ|||.L7|||L-7|L7F7F------7|||F-7LJF-JLJLJ||||L7|L7LJL7F-JF-JFJF7L7F7L7L7FJ|FJL7L--7L---JF7FJ|LJF7F||L--J-FJFJLJJ.J7-JJL.|-FJFFJ
F77FL-7LJL-JL-FJ|F-JLJL7FJL7||LJLF----JLJ|L7|F7L----7FJ|||F||-L7F-JL-7L7FJFJL-J||FJFJL7||F-JF7FJF7F7FJLJ|L--J|FJL-----JFJF77F7JJ|.-7.|..F7L-
F7-JLJ-77FLF--|FJL----7|L-7|||F--JF7F7F7FL-JLJ|F--7FJL7|||FJL7FJL7F77L7||FJ7F-7|||FJF7||||F-JLJFJLJ||F7|FF---JL7F---7F-JFJ|F-7|F7-|7.L7-F|-J
||J-FJFLFJL-.FLJJLF--7|L--J|LJL---JLJLJ|F7F--7|L-7LJF-JLJ|L-7|L-7|||F-J||L-7|FJ|LJL7|LJ|||L7F-7|F--J||L7FJF7F7-|L-7.LJF7L7LJFJF7L7.7-L|7|.|.
|J.||LL7L7-|.|LF77L-7LJF--7L--7F-------J|LJF-JL7FJF7L---7L-7||F-J|||L-7||F-J|L7L--7|L7FJ|||LJ-LJ|F--JL7|L-JLJL-JF7L7F-JL-JF7L-J|-F7J-F-JL77.
|LFL7J.|-F7|-JF|L--7L--JF7L--7LJF----7F-JF7L-7JLJFJ|F7.FJF-J||L-7||L7FJLJ|F7|FJF-7|L7||FJL7JF7F7LJF7JFJL----7F7FJL7LJF7F--JL---J7||.||J..JJF
..77|..|-|||F--L--7L7F--JL---JF7|F--7LJF-J|F7L--7L7|||FJFJ|FJL-7|LJFJL-7FJ||||FL7|L7|||L7FJFJ||L7FJ|FJF7F7F7LJLJF7L--JLJFF7F7F--7||F-7|F|.-7
FFF7FF7|7.7L777F7-L7|L------7FJ||L-7|F7L-7LJ|F--J.||||L7|F7L-7FJ|F-JF7FJL7|||L7FJL7||||FJ|JL7LJFJL7LJFJLJLJ|F7F-JL7F7F7F-J||LJF-J|||FJ7-777F
FF||--JL|-F7F7FJL--JL-7F7F--J|FJ|F-JLJL--JF7|L7F-7||||FJ|||F-JL7|L-7||L7FJ|||FJL7FJ||||L7L-7L7FJ|LL-7|F----J|||F--J|||LJF-J|F-JF7|||L--7|7FJ
LLLJ7.F-LF|||LJF7F7F-7|||L---JL-JL----7F-7||L-JL7LJ|||L7|||L-7FJ|F-J||FJL7|||L7FJL7|||L-JF-JFJL-77F7LJL7F---JLJL---JLJF-JF7||F7|LJLJF--J7JJ|
|LJ.F|JLLFJLJF7|LJLJ||||L7F7F-----7F--J|FJ|L7FF7L-7|||FJ||L7FJL-JL7-||L7FJ|||FJL7FJ||L--7L7FJF--JFJL7F7LJF7F-7F-------J7FJLJLJLJF--7L--7L|-F
L7J.F|7||L-7FJ||F----J||FJ||L----7LJF7FJL7L7|FJL-7||||L7||FJL--7F-JFJL7||FJLJL7FJL7||F77L7LJFJJF7L7FJ|L-7|LJFJL---------JF-7F7F7L-7L---JF-7J
JJFFF|7-FJFLJ|LJL----7LJL-J|F7F7-L-7||L7FJ|||L7F7LJ|||J|||L-7F-J|F7L-7|||L-7F-JL-7||||L--JF-JF7||FJL7|F7LJF7L---7F-7F7F7FJF|||||F7L--7JF7JLF
L-|J||-J|.7JLLF------JF-7F7|||||F7.LJL7||F7|L7LJL-7||L7||L7FJL-7LJ|F7|LJL7FJL--7FJLJ|L--7FJF-J||LJF-J||L--JL--77LJFLJ|||L7FJ|LJLJL7F-J-F|-J|
L7JFJ|FFJ-JJ7||F---7F7|FJ||LJLJLJL----J||||L7L7F-7||L7||L-JL77FJF-J|LJF--JL-7F-JL--7|FF-JL7L-7|L7FJF7LJF---7F-JF7F7F7LJ|FJL7L--7-FJ|-JL7LLL-
FLF7L|J-L--F|7LJF7FJ|||L-JL7F7F7F---7F7||||FJFJL7||L7|LJF7F-JFJFJF7L-7L-7F-7||F7F7FJL7L--7L7FJ|FJ|FJ|F-JF-7|L--JLJLJL-7LJJ-L7F-JL|FJ7-7.--7|
7-FF7LL|||FFF-7-||L7||L7F--J|||LJ-F-J|||||||FJF7||L7|L-7|LJF7L7||||F7L-7|L7|||||||L7FJF7FL7||FJ|FJ|FJL--JFJ|F--7F--7F7L-7FFFJ|F7F||L|7F-|-LJ
.F--L--||7-FJFJFJ|FJ|L7|L7F-JLJF-7L7FJLJLJ||L7||||FJ|F-J|F7|L7||FJLJ|F7|L7|||||||L7|L7||F7||||FJL7|L7F7F7|FJL7L|L-7LJ|F-J7.L7||L7||.7-|JL--J
-|JL||.FLF7L7|LL7|L-JLLJFJ|F-7F|FJFJL--7F-J|.|||||L7|L-7LJLJFJ|||FF-J|LJ7LJ|||||L7||F||||||||||F-J|FJ|||LJL-7L7|F7L-7LJF77FFJLJFJLJJL|...L7.
.L7|LJF7J||F||F-J|F--7F7L-JL7L-JL-JF7F-J|F-JFJ|LJL7|L7FJF---JFJ|L7L-7L----7||LJ|FJ||FJ|||LJ||LJ|F7||FJ|L---7|FJ||L--JF-JL7FJF--J|FLJ-7.L7LF-
J.-J7-|L-JL7||L-7|L-7LJ|F7..L--7F7FJ|L7FJ|F-JFJF7F||-|L7|F7F-J7L7|F7|F7F7FJ|L7FJL7||L7||L-7LJ|FJ||||L7L7F--J|L7|L----JF-7|L7L--7F-.L|.|F7L-7
FJ.F-7L-7F7LJL--JL--JF7LJL7F7F7LJ|L7|FJ|FJL-7L-J|FJL7|FJ|||L---7|||LJ||||||L7|L7FJ||FJ||F-J7F-JFJ|||FJFJL--7L-J|F----7L7LJF|F--J7.L-7|-LJF7L
FJF|-|7FJ||F-7F-7F--7|L-7FJ|LJL--JFJ|L7||F--JF7FJ|F7|LJ7LJL7F-7|LJ|F7||||L-7LJL|L7||L-J|L7F-JF7L7LJ|L7|F-7FJF7-|L---7L-JJLF|L-7J|F.FLJL--JFL
-.F|7|FL7|LJFJL7||F-J|F-JL-JF-7F7FJ|L-JLJL-7FJ||7|||L---7F7||-LJF-J|||||L7FJ|F-JFJLJF--JFJL-7||FJLFJFJ||FJ|FJL7|F7F7L----7.L7FJ7|.FJ--77|7||
J7.LFLJFLJ-|L7FJLJL-7|L-7F7FJFJ||L-7F---7F7|L7||FJ|L7F--J|LJL--7L--J||LJF||F7L-7L--7L-7FJ-F-J|||F-JFJFJ|L7LJF7||||||F----J-JLJJ7||J|F|7-FFJ.
|.|-7-L7L|F-FJL7-F--JL7FJ|||FL7||F-JL--7LJLJFJ|||FJFJ|F7.|F-7F-JF---JL--7|||L--JF-7|F-J|F7|F7|||L-7L7L7|7L7FJLJ|||||L---7JLFJLF-7|L|LLJJJ|LL
7-FFL-J|F.FL|F-JFJF--7||FJ||F-J||||F7F7L--7FJ|LJ|L7L7LJ|FJ|FJL-7L-7F7F7FJ||L---7L7||L-7LJ|LJLJLJF7|FJFJL7||L--7LJ||L--7FJLF7J7|J7|-7|.LJLLF.
|.L-L7.|.FF-J|F-JFJJFJ|||FJ||F7|||FJLJL---JL--7FJFJFJF7|L7||F-7L-7||||LJLLJF7F-JFJ|L-7|F7L7F--7FJLJL7|F7L7|F--JF-JL--7||J7J|-F-7L-J|-7|7.FL-
--|-JL|-F-L-7|L--JF7L-JLJL7|||||||L---7F7F7F--JL7|FL7|||FJ|||FJF7|LJ|L-7F7FJLJF7L7L-7||||FJL-7LJF-7FJ||L7||L-7L|F7F-7|LJJ|J|J.L|JJF|7F-|F7FJ
..F7-F.L||.L||F7F7|L------J|||||||F---J|LJ|L-7F-JL7LLJLJL7|LJL7|||F-JF7|||L-7FJL7L-7||LJ|L-7FJF-JFJL7|L7|||F7L7LJ||7LJJJ77F.F|FJJL-|L|-J7|LJ
F|L|.L|-LJ-|LJ|LJLJF7F-7F-7|||||LJL---7|F-JF-JL-7FJF7F--7LJF7FJ||||F-JLJ|L--JL77|F-JLJF-JF7|L7|F-JF-J|FJ||||L7L-7|L7|LL---J-L7LJ-FLLFL-..|F7
LL7JFJL7.L--JFL-7F7|||FJ|FJ|||||F-----J||F7L--7FJL-JLJF7|LFJLJFJLJ||7F-7L-7F-7L7LJLF77L-7||L7LJL-7L-7|L7|||L7L7FJ|FJ77|FJ-JJLJ7J.LJ|.F|J7.FJ
.LJ.|LFF-L.L|F|F||||LJL7|L-JLJ|||F----7||||F--J|F7F7F-JLJFJF-7L7LFJL-JFJF-JL7L7L---JL7F7LJL7|F---JF7||FJ||L7L7|L7LJ|JLJ-7FJ|7|F7.FF|J7JL7F|7
F.F7-F.||LFF7.|L||||7F7|L-7F77||||F---J||||L-77|||||L-7FFJFJFJFJFJF7F7|FJF7FJFJF7F7F7LJL--7LJL7F7FJ|||L7|L7L7|L7L--7L|7L|.|F-LJ--7JFJLF7L-JJ
L|7|J.FL7-L7J-|LLJ|L7|LJF-J|L-J|LJL---7|LJ|F7L7LJ|||F-JFJFJFL7L7L7|LJ||L7||L7L7|||||L--7F-JF--J|||FJ||FJL7|FJL7|F-7L7|FJ|7||||JJ|L7JJLLJJJF7
F-.|7FF-||.-JFL7|FJFJL-7L-7L7F7L7F----J|.FJ|L7|F7LJ|L-7|FJJF7L7L7|L-7|L7|||FJ7||LJ|L--7|L7.L--7|||L-J|L-7||L7FJLJJ|FJ-L77F|FF||||J|.7.L|7|-|
-JL|-||||F|F---F-JFJF--JF7|7|||FJL-----JFJFJJ|LJL-7|F-JLJF7||||FJL-7||FJ|||L-7||F-JF7FJL7|F---J||L--7|F-JLJJ|L-7--|||L-|---F-LJ-|FL7.|.--F.|
F-.|7|JFF7-JLLF|F7|FL7F7|||FJ|LJ|F------JFJF-JF7F7|||F--7||||FJL--7|||||LJ|F-JLJL7FJ|L7-LJ|F-7FJ|F-7||L7JF--JF-JFFLJJLLLFJ-LJ.LFLF-J.L7JFJF7
JFF|-LF|-FJ7.F-LJLJF-J|LJ|||FJJF-JF7F--7FJFJF7|LJLJLJ|F7LJLJLJF--7|||LJF7.|L---7FJL7L7L--7||FJ|FJL7|||FJFJF-7L--7-J|F-JL|7F|.LFJ.|L|-FJ||-7|
|-JL--7.LJ|FF|.LLJFL7FJFFLJ|||-L-7|LJF-JL7|FJ|L----7|LJL7F7F-7L-7||||F7|L-JF7F-J|F-JFJF7FJ||L7|L-7|LJ||-|FJJ|F7FJJ|FJJ.F7F-J.|.LL7-J.7.FJ7LJ
|L---J|7L-7LLF-J..FLLJLF-J.||7-L|LJ.SJF7FJLJFJF7F--JF---J|||FJF-J|||||LJF7FJLJF7LJFL|FJ||FJ|FJ|JFJL-7LJJ||7.||LJL7FF7.7FL7|J.F7-||FJ-LLJ.||.
F-J-|FFL77FF7|L-7-|J-J-J|.FLJJ7LLLF7L-J||F7.L7|LJF-7L----J||L7L7LLJLJL7FJ||F--JL--7J|L7||L7|L7L7|F7FJF|.LJ7-LJ-|J|FJF-77L|LF.F-JF|J|F.|.J7F7
|F|7.JJ|LJ|L-.F-J||.FL--7FLLJ||77L||F--JLJL-7||F7L7L------JL7L7L-7F---JL7|||F-7F-7L7|FJ||-LJJ|FJLJ|L-7J7.||.|.F|.F|L||.-.|L|JJLFL7FJJ||||.7|
LJFJ77J|J-LJ.7J-LF-F7L--|J7LLJJJLFJLJF-7F7F7||LJL7L-7F-7F7F7L7|F-JL--7F7||LJL7|L7L-JLJLLJL|F7|L-7||F7|77J.L-LJ7--|J-JJF|7L-J.LFJ-|-.LLJLLJ77
FLL-F-.LFFJJ.L77..|L--|7||LJ....|L---JFJ|LJ|||F7FJF-JL7LJ|||FJ|L-7F7FJ|||L7F-JL-JJLJ|LJ|JFFJLJF7|-LJLJJJ7..FL||-7|L.L7FLJLL77-L7.-.F--|7.LF|
F|LFJ.7J|.7.FF-L7FLJJ7|.LF7.77FFF----7L7L7FJ|LJ|||L7F7|F-J|||FJF7||LJFJLJ-|L---7-F-7|-F---L--7|LJJL|7L77FFJ7.J--LL7.FL7.F|-F-.|FFJ.|JJF|--J|
||-|-7-7777|-7-FLLJ|.J.F7|J-.L--L-7F7L7|FJL7|F-JL7FJ|||L7FJLJL7|LJL7FJ7LF-JF--7L-7J7J|.FJ|.JL|L77FFL-.-F-J-|-7||LLF7.F--77.|.FJ|.||||7L-7JJ|
LL-7-.LLJL-JFJJL||JL77F|J-7|.7.|||LJL7LJL7LLJL-7FJL-J|L7||7-F-JL-7FJ|F--JF7L7-L7FJ.|7|FL-7.|-L-JJFL7L7|LJ|-|.-L|7J|L--JFJ7--F7.J-||LF-LL-J||
FL7J---JL-L--.F.L77L--FLJ|-7-J7LF----JF-7L-7F7JLJJ7|.L7|LJ-FJF7F-JL-J|F7FJL7|JLLJFFJLL7-|J.L-7.L-|.|7.|7-|.L7LL|JFL7FL-7-J.FLJ-|FJ||L7LFJ.F-
F.J.||7L|..-|--JL|F--FL7FL.F.LF-L---7FJFJF7LJ|J-FL|--LLJ.JJL-J||-LJ.LLJ|L7FJL7..J-L-|-J7|F-LL|-7FLF--.F7JL-.-J.L-|LFLFJJ|LF-FJ--L7L-L|-J7F7|
|F|FLF|F--F--J.J7||7--7|7..-.FJ.|J.||L7|FJL7FJJFFJL-7J.J-7L||F|L7FFLJ.LL7|L7FJJ7LLL7|||L.L.F||7-LFJ.LFJ-77LJJF77.LF-JF-J-FJ-LJ.|F|LF-L.LLF7J
J-FJ.-JL|J.-L--JFJL-FJ-L|J--|LL-7.-LL-JLJ-LLJJ-L7-L7J--J-7.7--L-J-JL|-LLLJLLJ-LJ.L-LJ--..L-|-JJ-L|---|7JFL-L--J|-F-J-|-JJFJ-LJ-LL7-7LJ-7L-JJ
```

I tryed adding `root.setCache(true);` and `root.setCacheHint(CacheHint.SPEED);` to my program and it works but the quality drops so much it doesn't work for me. I also tryed `root.setCacheHint(CacheHint.QUALITY);` but makes the render look really dim and I would not prefer this option as solution.

Comment: If i remove `rectangle.setStroke(Color.WHITE);` from the `GridTile` class I am still experiencing a lot of lag. Also how would I limit the number of nodes that need to be rendered if my code makes so all nodes need to be rendered when resizing the window because I want the whole grid to be shown. Maybe I don't understand something (highly possible)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467719/what-is-the-best-way-to-display-millions-of-images-in-java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44136040/performance-of-javafx-gui-vs-swing/44141878#44141878

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43808639/how-to-create-totally-custom-javafx-control-or-how-to-create-pane-with-dynamic/43814198#43814198

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to improve performance

To increase performance you need to do *both* of these things:

1. Limit the number of nodes you need to render in the scene.
2. Don't set a z-coordinate for nodes.

Interestingly, even if you set scene antialiasing and depth buffering off, your application still renders very slowly for large grids when you have a z coordinate set (the line `this.shape.setTranslateZ(-1);` in your GridTile10 class).  JavaFX probably switches some optimizations off when it encounters different z values (I don't know exactly what causes the slowness).

But even without setting the z-coordinate, your rendering is still slow because you have a lot of nodes.  A lot of the nodes are arc-style nodes, which might challenge the rendering system, because if you don't render the arcs, so you just have rectangles and lines, performance is much better, but even then performance is still not ideal.

An example timed performance table for the large grid, which renders 58227 nodes, on my machine (MacBook Pro).

- 9 seconds -> With arcs, lines, and rectangles, and different z coordinates.
- 3 seconds -> With arcs, lines, and rectangles, and the same z coordinates (0).
- 1 second -> With only lines and rectangles.

So to fix your problem it is advisable to take a different approach.

Some options are:

1. Construct a single [`Path`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/Path.html) for your grid lines rather than multiple nodes, similarly for the pipe connectors that you layer on top of the nodes OR
2. Render elements in a [`Canvas`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html) OR
3. Implement or use a [tile engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tile-based_video_game), potentially using [tiled rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiled_rendering).

#### Benchmarking using the pulse logger

When JavaFX detects that some part of its rendering pipeline is running slowly it output logs to a pulse logger, which you can switch on to gather performance data on the application, using this VM property when running the application.

```
-Djavafx.pulseLogger=true
```

The pulse logger is an undocumented feature whose output can be hard to understand.

#### Example using Paths

In the example below I converted your Node-based rendering to Path-based rendering.

The resultant scene for your large grid sample has only 3 nodes (the root group and a path for the grid, plus a path for the pipes that are displayed on top of the grid), as opposed to 58227 nodes in your implementation.

Performance is good on my system. I notice no lag initially rendering the scene, resizing the application window, or zooming in and out with the mouse scroll wheel.

There are advantages to treating everything as nodes rather than using Paths (nodes have a lot more modifiable properties than path elements), but there are performance tradeoffs as well to gain those advantages.  You will need to adapt an implementation that best meets your requirements.

This layered path approach is also an alternate solution to the z-based depth buffer sorting solution offered in the answer to your earlier related question:

- [How do I render my lines in front of my rectangles in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77761833/how-do-i-render-my-lines-in-front-of-my-rectangles-in-my-code)

*PathApp.java*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PathApp extends Application {
    private static final int GRID_SIZE = 40;
    private double zoomFactor = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ArrayList<String> pipes = readGridData(
//                SMALL_GRID
                LARGE_GRID
        );

        Group root = new Group(
                createGrid(GRID_SIZE, pipes),
                createPipes(GRID_SIZE, pipes)
        );

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);

        makeZoomable(scene, root);
        scene.widthProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> resetSize(scene, root));
        scene.heightProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> resetSize(scene, root));

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
        stage.setFullScreenExitHint("");
        stage.show();
    }

    private static ArrayList<String> readGridData(String input) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(
                input
        );
        ArrayList<String> pipes = new ArrayList<>();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            pipes.add(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        scanner.close();
        return pipes;
    }

    private void makeZoomable(Scene scene, Group root) {
        scene.setOnScroll((ScrollEvent event) -> {
            double deltaY = event.getDeltaY();

            if (deltaY > 0) {
                zoomFactor += 0.01;
            } else {
                zoomFactor -= 0.01;
                if (zoomFactor <= 0) {
                    zoomFactor = 0.01;
                }
            }
            updateTransforms(root);
        });
    }

    private static Node createGrid(int cellSize, ArrayList<String> grid) {
        final int nCols = grid.getFirst().length();
        final int nRows = grid.size();

        final int w = nCols * cellSize;
        final int h = nRows * cellSize;

        Path gridPath = new Path();
        gridPath.setStroke(Color.WHITE);

        for (int row = 0; row < nRows + 1; row++) {
            final int yOffset = row * cellSize;
            gridPath.getElements().addAll(
                    new MoveTo(0, yOffset),
                    new LineTo(w, yOffset)
            );
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < nCols + 1; col++) {
            final int xOffset = col * cellSize;
            gridPath.getElements().addAll(
                    new MoveTo(xOffset, 0),
                    new LineTo(xOffset, h)
            );
        }

        return gridPath;
    }

    private static Node createPipes(int cellSize, ArrayList<String> grid) {
        final int nCols = grid.getFirst().length();
        final int nRows = grid.size();

        final int w = nCols * cellSize;
        final int h = nRows * cellSize;

        final int halfGridSize = cellSize / 2;

        Path pipePath = new Path();
        pipePath.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
        pipePath.setStrokeWidth(5);
        ObservableList<PathElement> pipeElements = pipePath.getElements();
        for (int row = 0; row < nRows; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < nCols; col++) {
                final int x = col * GRID_SIZE;
                final int y = row * GRID_SIZE;

                char pipeChar = grid.get(row).charAt(col);

                switch (pipeChar) {
                    case '-' -> pipeElements.addAll(
                            new MoveTo(x, y + halfGridSize),
                            new LineTo(x + GRID_SIZE, y + halfGridSize)
                    );
                    case '|' -> pipeElements.addAll(
                            new MoveTo(x + halfGridSize, y),
                            new LineTo(x + halfGridSize, y + GRID_SIZE)
                    );
                    case 'F' -> {
                            ArcTo arcTo = new ArcTo();
                            arcTo.setX(x + halfGridSize);
                            arcTo.setY(y + GRID_SIZE);
                            arcTo.setRadiusX(halfGridSize);
                            arcTo.setRadiusY(halfGridSize);

                            pipeElements.addAll(
                                    new MoveTo(x + GRID_SIZE, y + halfGridSize),
                                    arcTo
                            );
                    }
                    case 'L' -> {
                        ArcTo arcTo = new ArcTo();
                        arcTo.setX(x + GRID_SIZE);
                        arcTo.setY(y + halfGridSize);
                        arcTo.setRadiusX(halfGridSize);
                        arcTo.setRadiusY(halfGridSize);

                        pipeElements.addAll(
                                new MoveTo(x + halfGridSize, y),
                                arcTo
                        );
                    }
                    case '7' -> {
                        ArcTo arcTo = new ArcTo();
                        arcTo.setX(x);
                        arcTo.setY(y + halfGridSize);
                        arcTo.setRadiusX(halfGridSize);
                        arcTo.setRadiusY(halfGridSize);

                        pipeElements.addAll(
                                new MoveTo(x + halfGridSize, y + GRID_SIZE),
                                arcTo
                        );
                    }
                    case 'J' -> {
                        ArcTo arcTo = new ArcTo();
                        arcTo.setX(x + halfGridSize);
                        arcTo.setY(y);
                        arcTo.setRadiusX(halfGridSize);
                        arcTo.setRadiusY(halfGridSize);

                        pipeElements.addAll(
                                new MoveTo(x, y + halfGridSize),
                                arcTo
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return pipePath;
    }

    private void resetSize(Scene scene, Group root) {
        root.setLayoutX((scene.getWidth() - root.prefWidth(-1)) / 2);
        root.setLayoutY((scene.getHeight() - root.prefHeight(-1)) / 2);

        double scaleX = scene.getWidth() / root.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
        double scaleY = scene.getHeight() / root.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();
        zoomFactor = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY) - 0.01;
        updateTransforms(root);
    }

    private void updateTransforms(Group root) {
        root.setScaleX(zoomFactor);
        root.setScaleY(zoomFactor);
    }

    // 597 nodes
    private static final String SMALL_GRID =
            """
            FF7FSF7F7F7F7F7F---7
            L|LJ||||||||||||F--J
            FL-7LJLJ||||||LJL-77
            F--JF--7||LJLJ7F7FJ-
            L---JF-JLJ.||-FJLJJ7
            |F|F-JF---7F7-L7L|7|
            |FFJF7L7F-JF7|JL---7
            7-L-JL7||F7|L7F-7F7|
            L.L7LFJ|||||FJL7||LJ
            L7JLJL-JLJLJL--JLJ.L
            """;

    // 58227 nodes
    private static final String LARGE_GRID =
            """
            // input.txt data from your question.  
            """;
}
```

#### Output

Small grid

[image: small grid]

Large grid

[image: large grid]