# JavaFX rendering issue: robots moving under tiles in GridPane when facing right or down

Tags: java, javafx, game-development

I am developing a JavaFX application for a game where robots move on a grid of tiles. I'm encountering a rendering issue where the robots, represented by Pane objects in a GridPane, move under the tiles instead of over them when facing right or down. This issue does not occur when the robots are facing up or left.

When the robot faces right or down and moves, it is rendered under the tiles. When facing up or left, the robot correctly renders over the tiles. The issue persists despite attempts to manage the Z-order using toFront() and setViewOrder(-100.0).

- Relevant code using Java:

```
public void updateRobot(RobotType robotType, Position newPosition, Orientation newOrientation) {
    Robot robot = this.robots.get(robotType);
    if (robot == null) {
        return;
    }

    Position oldPosition = robot.getPosition();
    ImageView robotImageView = getRobotImageView(robotType);

    if (oldPosition != null && robotImageView != null) {
        // Calculate the movement delta
        double deltaX = (newPosition.x() - oldPosition.x()) * TILE_SIZE;
        double deltaY = (newPosition.y() - oldPosition.y()) * TILE_SIZE;

        // Bring the robot's pane to the front before starting the transition
        Pane robotPane = robotPanes.get(robotType);
        if (robotPane != null) {
            robotPane.toFront();
        }

        // Create a movement transition
        TranslateTransition moveTransition = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(2), robotImageView);
        moveTransition.setToX(robotImageView.getTranslateX() + deltaX);
        moveTransition.setToY(robotImageView.getTranslateY() + deltaY);

        // Determine the new rotation angle and calculate the angle difference
        double newAngle = getRotationAngle(newOrientation);
        double currentAngle = robotImageView.getRotate();
        double angleDelta = newAngle - currentAngle;

        if (angleDelta > 180) {
            angleDelta -= 360;
        } else if (angleDelta < -180) {
            angleDelta += 360;
        }

        // Create a rotation transition
        RotateTransition rotateTransition = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(1), robotImageView);
        rotateTransition.setByAngle(angleDelta);


        // Play both transitions sequentially
        SequentialTransition sequentialTransition = new SequentialTransition(moveTransition, rotateTransition);
        sequentialTransition.setOnFinished(event -> {
            robot.setOrientation(newOrientation);
            robot.setPosition(newPosition);

            // Move the robot's pane to the new tile
            Pane oldTile = getTile(oldPosition.x(), oldPosition.y());
            Pane newTile = getTile(newPosition.x(), newPosition.y());
            if (robotPane != null) {
                oldTile.getChildren().remove(robotPane);
                newTile.getChildren().add(robotPane);
                robotPane.setViewOrder(-100.0); // Ensure the robot's pane is at the front after transition
            }

            // Reset translation and rotation to new values
            robotImageView.setTranslateX(0);
            robotImageView.setTranslateY(0);
            robotImageView.setRotate(newAngle);
        });

        sequentialTransition.play();
    } else {
        robot.setOrientation(newOrientation);
        robot.setPosition(newPosition);
        drawRobots();
    }
}
```

```
public void drawRobots() {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        for (Robot robot : this.robots.values()) {
            Position position = robot.getPosition();
            if (position == null) {
                continue;
            }

            Pane robotsPane = robotPanes.computeIfAbsent(robot.getRobotType(), k -> {
                Pane newPane = new Pane();
                newPane.setPrefSize(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
                ImageView imageView = getImageView(robot.getRobotType().getGameFileName(), getRotationAngle(robot.getOrientation()));
                newPane.getChildren().add(imageView);
                newPane.setViewOrder(-100.0); // Lower Z-order for robots
                return newPane;
            });

            Pane newTile = getTile(position.x(), position.y());
            newTile.getChildren().add(robotsPane);
        }
    });
}
```

```
public void drawTile(int x, int y) {
    List<Tile> tiles = this.map.getTilesAtPosition(x, y);
    if (tiles == null) {
        return;
    }
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        Pane tilePane = createMapCell(tiles, x, y);
        tilePane.setViewOrder(100.0); // Higher Z-order for tiles
        this.grid.add(tilePane, x, y);
    });
}
```

I've tried using Pane.toFront() to bring the robot Pane to the front.
I've set a negative view order (setViewOrder(-100.0)) on the robot Panes.

I ensured that tiles are added to the GridPane before the robots.
Despite these attempts, the robots still render under the tiles when moving right or down. I am looking for suggestions or solutions to ensure the robots consistently render over the tiles, regardless of the direction of movement.

Comment: Off topic, but I don't think you should be using `runLater` here at all.

Comment: See this tutorial from Oracle -> [Working with the JavaFX SceneGraph](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/scene-graph-tutorial/scenegraph.htm#JFXSG107).  It has images of the tree structure of a scene graph.  Draw one for your application and put it the image you created in the question.

Comment: Nodes in the scene graph will be painted in the order top to bottom, left to right, of the tree you drew, according to a [painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm).  The view order will only affect the order within child siblings of the same immediate parent.  If you want to rely only on the painting order, then you need to ensure the order is correct for your app.  Or you can use [z co-ordinates with depth buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77761833/how-do-i-render-my-lines-in-front-of-my-rectangles-in-my-code/77762200#77762200).